# Get access token for my application from the GoogleApiClient in Android

Tags: android, google-plus, access-token

I'm currently working on a application and I have integrate GooglePlus Api in it. My app is successful in logging in using google account, but i am unable to get the access token. I followed steps provided by developer.google.com and solutions provided for similar questions posted in Stackoverflow.

Eg.

```
 AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String token = null;

                try {
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(),
                            "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
                } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                    // Network or server error, try later
                    Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
                } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                    // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                    // assuming you have already verified that 
                    // Google Play services is installed.
                    Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
                }

                return token;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
            }

        };
        task.execute();
```

`mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName()` method is not woking for me (i.e when i type `mGoogleApiClient.` there is no such method called `getAccountName()` to select).
Is this because i have implemented the GoogleApi inside the fragment? OR

Is there any reason for this.

Please help me solve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found what i was looking for, I used `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient)` instead of `mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName()` and it worked out.